# MySQL query with boolean involved

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanna do something with my db, I have a table which includes a row called online, with 0 and 1 as "atributes". Now, I want to update all users ranks when their online. I already tried `update users set rank = "2" where 'online' = true` but it didn't work. Then I tried `update users set rank = "2" where 'online' = 1` didn't work either.

Any answers?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `online`, since that's a column and not a variable/value. Plus, depending on how your query/code is actually setup, you may want to switch the double quotes to singles for `rank = "2"` which should read something like `"update users set rank = '2' where online = 1";`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Put that as answer; else I will do it :).

Comment: @Rahul You have my blessing ;-)

Comment: ^--« That translates to "please do" ;-) @Rahul cheers (I'm done with "answers")